# Let a be a real number and let $S = \{ x \in Q : x <a \}.$ prove that $a = sup S.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let a be a real number and let $S = \{ x \in Q : x <a \}.$ prove that $a = sup S.$

I know the proof of the theorem given below, which I feel very similar to the proof of the required problem:

> [image]

But exactly how will they differ, could any one tell me How?

**My attempt is:**
It is obvious that the set $S$ is a nonempty set that is bounded above by $a$, so by the completeness axiom it has a least upper bound, say $s$. Suppose to the contrary that $a \neq s$ then there exists $y \in S$ such that $x \leq y$ for all $x \in S$ and $y < a$. but after this how can I complete? could anyone help me please?

Comment: The proofs are different because the claims are different. The linked theorem proves that $\sup A$ is an integer, which you don't have to prove.

Comment: I have edited my attempt .... could you please tell me what can I do to complete?@5xum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the density of Rationals in Real Numbers to prove your result.

To prove that $a$ is the supremum of the given, set we shall exploit its property that any number less than $a$ cannot be an upper bound for the set.

Therefore, take $\epsilon > 0$ (arbitrarily). Then consider the number $a - \epsilon$. Clearly, $a - \epsilon < a$ is a real number. Now, by density of rationals in real numbers, $\exists q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a - \epsilon < q < a$. Since $q < a$, we have $q \in S$ and also $q > a - \epsilon$ and hence $a - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $S$. Since this is true for all $\epsilon$, we can conclude that $a$ is the supremum of $S$.

Comment: you mean by the density of rational numbers in real numbers the property that:"between any 2 distinct real numbers there exist a rational number"?

Comment: Yes! Exactly the same.